# Python ternary operator check most left reference

Tags: python, conditional-statements, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, ternary

What is the pythonic way to write a ternary operator like this in the shortest possible way?

```
(x!=null)? x.something:0;
```

I want to use something like

```
y = x.something or 0
```

but that will check references in a way such that

```
x.y.z = None whenever x or y are None
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, that's what i've been looking for !

Comment: So, do you want a ternary conditional operator, or something like the [null-conditional operator that exists in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)?

Comment: Found it in the marked answer. Basically: a if condition else b would be something like x.something if x else 0. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ok, that won't work for `x.y.z` as in your last example, though.

Comment: x.y.z if (x.y if x else None) else 0

Comment: Yup, but that approach doesn't exactly scale easily - `a.b.c.d.e.f` would look ugly :P